# Error managing catalog connection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, cross-site-publishing

I am getting an error while managing catalog connection in Cross Site Publishing:

> The shared catalog tagging field "" could not be found. You must select the tagging field for this catalog.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons that this error can occur - so keep these in mind:

- If you don't have any values in that field, it won't be found. Make sure you actually have some records in that list that use that field.
- If the crawler hasn't run, it won't be found.
- If the name of the term set or column changed, it could have problems.

Also keep in mind that if the items in your list require publishing or approval, the crawler might not recognize them until after they've been approved and the next crawl runs.

Hope this helps!